# MAC OS X Cocoa Application

Tags: macos, cocoa, opencv

I'm trying to make a Mac OS X Cocoa Application (not command line) with opencv 3.0 beta. I compiled Opencv succesfully, but i struck when I try to add it to my project. Can anybody have a example?

Answer (score 0):

I would first refer to this link, which is pretty simple:
http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/

this solution looks pretty complicated, but seems like it works as well:
http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/